# How to edit a multi-line scalar and print the edits

Tags: string, perl

I need to edit a multi-line scalar and print the results, however I am not able to do it neatly.

```
my $text = "$omething\n nothing\n Everything\n";
```

What I need to do is check each line, and if there's a capital letter or special charracter - print this line and remove it from the original scalar ($text).

In this example it would print two times, first time:

$omething

Second time:

Everything

And remove both of those strings from the $text scalar.

Comment: I siggest that you split by newline and use a regex on each part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To include a dollar sign in a double quoted string, you need to escape it by a backslash.

You can remove the matching lines in a while loop:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $text = "\$omething\nnothing\nEverything\n";

while ($text =~ s/(.*[[:upper:]\$].*\n)//) {
    print $1;
}
print "Remaining: $text";
```

A period never matches a newline (unless you specify the `/s` modifier).